# Compiling a C program that defines a function getline by GCC

Tags: gcc, glibc

I'm trying to compile by GCC an old C program that defines and uses a function named `getline`, which conflicts with the function of the same name in the GNU C library.  How can you compile it?  Passing `-ansi -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED` to GCC give me strange errors in `strings.h`:

```
/usr/include/strings.h:74:16: error: expected identifier or '(' before '__extension__'
```

The relevant lines in `strings.h` is:

```
extern char *index (__const char *__s, int __c)
 __THROW __attribute_pure__ __nonnull ((1));
```

Comment: You may get more answers on stackoverflow.  In the meantime, here is a [related SO question about overriding function calls in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617554/override-a-function-call-in-c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the `-fno-builtin-function` option to `gcc` works for built-in functions such as `malloc` and `strlen` (see [Other built-in functions provided by GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)), it does not work for `glibc` built-in GNU extensions such as the `getline` function.

Similar to some of the solutions pointed out by jw013's link, you may try to insert `#define` statements in the source files to rename the `getline` function defined by the program, e. g. `#define getline my_getline`.

Here's a small code example to illustrate this approach.

```
/*

gcc -Wall -Wextra -o mystrdup mystrdup.c

./mystrdup

*/

#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

// mystrdup.c:14: error: conflicting types for 'strdup'
//#define strdup my_strdup

char *strdup(char *str) {
   str = str;
   return str;
}

int main (void) { 
   char *str = 0;
   char mystr[] = "Hello, mystrdup!";
   str = strdup(mystr);
   printf("%s\n", str);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
gcc -fno-builtin-getline ...
```

For more information please see:

```
man gcc | less -p '-fno-builtin'
```

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

In the GCC documentation, their suggestion for dealing with this issue is to add the -ansi compiler switch because getline is a GCC extension to ansi.